# Why can't I drag the Facebook SDK into a new project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, facebook-ios-sdk

On [The Github page](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), it states:

> In Xcode, open the Facebook SDK by selecting File->Open... and selecting src/facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj.
>   With your own application project open in Xcode, drag and drop the "FBConnect" folder from the Facebook SDK project into your application's project.

I know this worked for me earlier this year, using Xcode 3.x and iOS 4.x, but now I'm doing a new project in Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 and it doesn't work anymore. I'm unable to drag the folder into my project. Any ideas? What should I do instead?

Comment: Did anyone get a solution to this problem? A workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a better idea to just include all the necessary files directly into your project - so everything inside the src directory, excluding the .pch and .xcodeproj files.

Also, it sounds like you found a bug in Xcode 4.2, so it might be a good idea to submit a bug report to http://bugreport.apple.com :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in XCode 4.2. Just file a report with Apple. I have filed one too. More the number of reports, chances are they'll get a fix out earlier.

For now, I just use a mac with an older version of XCode, add any SDKs I need to add and then open the project again with the new version. That works :)